# Fetching collection with backbone.js but id for each model is not set

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

In short, I'm fetching a collection but afterwards I'm unable to get a specific entity from the collection using either its `id` or `cid`.

For this problem, consider my two REST endpoints `/sites` and `/sites/some-site-id/entities`
Both `sites` and `entities` are collections. Here are my models/collections:

**Models / collections**

```
var ROOT = 'http://localhost:5000';

Entity = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    defaults: {
        xpos: 10,
        ypos: 10,
        site: "default"
    }
});

Entities = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Entity,
    ownUrl: '/entities',
    site: {},
    url: function() {
        return ROOT + "/sites/" + (this.site? this.site : 'null') + this.ownUrl;
    },
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        if(!options.site) throw new Error("No site associated with entities");
        if(!options.site.get("_id")) throw new Error("Associated site has no _id");

        this.site = options.site.get("_id");
    }
});

Site = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute: "_id",
    defaults: {
        name: "default",
        description: "My site"
    }
});

Sites = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Site,
    url: ROOT + "/sites"
});
```

My problem is that when I'm fetching the entities for a site, I cannot lookup a certain entity from the collection using the [`get`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-get) method on collection. I simply get `undefined` returned.

This is how I test it (entities.fetch will get 4 entities):

**Test code**

```
var site1 = new Site({id : "52813a2888c84c9953000001"});
sites.add(site1);
site1.fetch({success: function(model, response, options) {
    entities = new Entities([], {site: site1});
    entities.fetch({success: function(model, response, options) {
        entities.each(function (entity) {
            console.log("entity.get(\"_id\") = " + entity.get("_id"));
            console.log("entity.id = " + entity.id);
            console.log("Looking up entity using id (" + entity.get("_id") + "): " + entities.get(entity.get("_id")));
            console.log("Looking up entity using cid (" + entity.cid + "): " + entities.get(entity.cid));
            console.log("");
        });
    }});
}});
```

When I run this, I get:

**Test result**

```
entity.id = undefined
entity.get("_id") = 528146ade34176b255000003
Looking up entity using id (528146ade34176b255000003): undefined 
Looking up entity using cid (c1): undefined

entity.id = undefined
entity.get("_id") = 528146ade34176b255000002
Looking up entity using id (528146ade34176b255000002): undefined
Looking up entity using cid (c2): undefined

entity.id = undefined
entity.get("_id") = 528146ade34176b255000001
Looking up entity using id (528146ade34176b255000001): undefined
Looking up entity using cid (c3): undefined

entity.id = undefined
entity.get("_id") = 528146ade34176b255000004
Looking up entity using id (528146ade34176b255000004): undefined
Looking up entity using cid (c4): undefined
```

What I would expect is for the collection to return the specific entity. Does it have something to do with my special idAttribute "_id" (for compliance with mongodb)?

**EDIT**

Apparently it seems to have something to do with my idAttribute. Because if I add an "id" field to every entity returned, I can lookup entities using its id. Like so on server side:

```
function getEntitiesInSite(siteId, fun) {
    db.siteentities.find({site: mongojs.ObjectId(siteId)}, function(err, entities) {
        entities.forEach(function (entity) {
            entity.id = entity._id;
        });
        fun(err, entities);
    });
}
```

This isn't exactly what I wanted and I can imagine that I would run into other problems in the future with inconsistent id's (having both `id` and `_id` fields).

Answer (score 1):

the root of problems is your models' `id` attribute is not set.

`id` is only checked and set to your `idAttribute` when the model's `set` method is called.

When you fetch from collection successfully, there is no call to `set` function of the model. So `id` is `undefined` for models.

you need to trigger `set` event in each of your `entity` model in order for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I was running an old version of backbone.js. Which obviously couldn't be noticed by anyone else, since I didn't add that information to the question.

With backbone.js 1.1.0 and underscore 1.4.4 everything works just fine.